# How can I install BlueGriffon 2.0 from a deb package or PPA?

Tags: ppa, bluegriffon

Is it possible to install [BlueGriffon 2.0](http://bluegriffon.org/index.html#download) from a deb package or PPA?

[image]

Comment: GetDeb only seems to have version [1.7](http://www.getdeb.net/updates/Ubuntu/16.04/?q=bluegriffon).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I know of, but the install is very easy, you download the tar, unpack it to a location, like your home, and then you run the bluegriffon app from there, after you start it, you can lock it to your start bar, and then just click on the icon from there, it really is that easy to install.

http://nixmash.com/linux/how-to-install-blue-griffon-in-ubuntu-and-linux-mint/

Answer (score 2):

It is even simpler now, with the version of January 2017 and Ubuntu 16:

The file is a `.deb`, you click on it, and it opens a window for installation. Just click "Install", it will ask you for permission, and that's all. It only did not notify about having finished the installation.